# failed instal 'Google GCM' swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I failed to install Google Cloud Messaging and got this error

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `Google/CloudMessaging` required by `Podfile`
>
> Specs satisfying the `Google/CloudMessaging` dependency were found,
>   but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I tried to changing ios version in podfile and xcworkspace from 8.1 to 9.0 and still got same error. I'm using Cocoapods 1.1.0.beta.1

Answer (score 3):

I tried delete all pods files & reinstall pods and it works now